# Project upgrade from VS 2013 to VS 2015 windows 8.1 universal apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I was about to update my existing windows 8.1 universal app to VS2015 along with its portable projects.But it fails with below error

```
"Error : DEP6810 : MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 1004. See log file 'C:\xxx\xxx.WindowsPhone\obj\ARM\Debug\MDIL\MDILXapCompileLog.txt' for more details"
```

**The Log file Contents**

```
Error: Compile filter argument specified non-existent file: C:\xxx\xxx\xxx.WindowsPhone\obj\ARM\Debug\MSIL\PhoneLibrary\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Portable.dll
Invalid argument

Microsoft (R) MDIL XAP Compiler - Version 4.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Usage: MDILXAPCompile /In:<InputPath> /Out:<OutputPath> /Config:<ConfigPath> [/CompileFilter:<Assembly Path>;<Assembly Path>] [/Timeout:<Timeout>] [/Log:<LogPath>] [/AppX]

/In     - Path to directory containing files to process
/Out        - Path to directory to place processed files in
/Config     - Path to configuration file
/CompileFilter  - Optional restrictive list of assembly files in InputPath,
          separated by semi-colons, to be compiled.
/Timeout    - Optional timeout in milliseconds before killing the Crossgen process. Overrides config file timeout value. Use -1 for infinite timeout, 0 for application default (2 hours).
/Log        - Optional path to log file
/AppX       - Specifies that assemblies correspond to an AppX package

Relative paths are relative to this executable's directory.
```

I get this error only when I debug the project but it works normal when i generate package and deploy it to device.

Answers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved. But may not be the direct way. Its quite strange.

I referred my dll's from the folder(named as PhoneLibrary) inside the app.  As per log file location "C:\xxx\xxx\xxx.WindowsPhone\obj\ARM\Debug\MSIL\PhoneLibrary\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Portable.dll" it failed to create the folder.

So i just created folder in that location and copied my dll's in that folder and worked great.